# SSRS how to conditionally hide a cell if it's the first row of a parent group?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

This question is simple but I cannot find a good answer or actually an answer at all.

How do you conditionally hide a cell if it's the first row of a parent group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `RowNumber` and scope it to the parent group.  The visibility expression for the child group can then be something like:

```
=IIF(RowNumber("ParentGroup") = 1, True, False)
```